# Executing a ruby file without calling "ruby" on the terminal

Tags: ruby, bash

I have an app on a file named `todo` with this shebang in the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. On the terminal, I want to be able to run this file calling `todo new "Some Task"` and not `ruby todo new "Some task"`, but I can't make it work; I always get a `bash: todo: command not found`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on MacOsX 10.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it proper rights: `chmod +x todo`. And the file must be located in `$PATH`.

Comment: Ok, I did both, I changed the path with this command PATH=$PATH\:/dir/path. Works fine now, thank you.

Comment: Make sure to add that command to your ~/.profile or you'll have to run it every time you open a new shell.

Answer (score 2):

First, do `chmod +x todo`.

Second, put the file into your path either by moving it to a director that's already in your path or by editing your path.

To see what your path is now, do `echo $PATH`. You could move your file into any of the directories listed.

To edit your path, open ~/.profile and add the line `PATH=$PATH:/directory/of/todo`

Answer (score 2):

To execute file from current directory:

```
./todo new "Some Task"
```